# Ogre and Allegro direct3d device 9 conflict

Tags: windows, direct3d, ogre, allegro

I've been trying to write a program that uses Allegro 5 to handle 2D rendering and and Ogre for 3D rendering but I've had problems with initialization, I've got most of the issues down which were the hInstance of the window, but now the issue is that `Ogre::D3D9RenderWindow::setDevice()` only takes Ogre's type and that is set by an `ID3Device9` according to the Ogre API reference and not what `al_get_d3d9_device()` returns which is an `LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9`. I need help trying to figure out how to convert the `LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9` to a `ID3Device9`.

Here is the code the I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *al_display = NULL;

if(!al_init())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize allegro");
    return -1;
}

al_display = al_create_display(640, 480);

if(!al_display)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot initialize the display");
    return -1;
}

HWND hWnd = al_get_win_window_handle(al_display);

HINSTANCE hInst = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);

Ogre::D3D9RenderWindow ogre_window(hInst);

ogre_window.setDevice(al_get_d3d_device(al_display)); // Function only takes an Ogre::D3D9Device

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you use OpenGL. An [example](https://github.com/allefant/allegro/blob/master/examples/ex_ogre3d.cpp) comes with Allegro.

Not sure about D3D.

Answer (score 0):

After much work and tedious studying with the help of Matthew's answer I was able to find the solution to the problem through a few pointers on pointers.

Here is the final code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *al_display = NULL;

if(!al_init())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize allegro");
    return -1;
}

al_display = al_create_display(640, 480);

if(!al_display)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot initialize the display");
    return -1;
}

HWND hWnd = al_get_win_window_handle(al_display);

HINSTANCE hInst = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);

Ogre::D3D9RenderWindow ogre_window(hInst);

LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 D3dDev = al_get_d3d_device(al_display);
IDirect3DDevice9 *iD3dDev = D3dDev;
Ogre::D3D9DeviceManager D3dDevManager;
Ogre::D3D9Device *OD3dDev = D3dDevManager.getDeviceFromD3D9Device(iD3dDev);
ogre_window.setDevice(OD3dDev);

return 0;
}
```